# Xamarin Forms CollectionView Grouping Not Working With Intellisense

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, intellisense, collectionview

***The Issue***

I am getting extremely confused with how grouping works in the CollectionView.

I am able to get an output as expected using the recommended example from the Xamarin Documentation with the code below:

**CollectionView XAML**

```
<CollectionView IsGrouped="True" ItemsSource="{Binding CategoriesList}" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="10" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <SwipeView>

                        <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                            <SwipeItems>
                                <SwipeItem Text="Delete" IconImageSource="CategoryPhoto" />
                            </SwipeItems>
                        </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                        <SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <SwipeItems>
                                <SwipeItem Text="Edit" IconImageSource="CategoryPhoto" />
                            </SwipeItems>
                        </SwipeView.RightItems>

                        <SwipeView.Content>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">
                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EditProduct, Source={x:Reference Name=MainView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ID}" />
                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="15">
                                    <Image Source="CategoryPhoto" />
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" />
                                        <Label Text="doy" TextColor="Black" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                                        <Label Text="&#8854;" TextColor="Black" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Property=Height, Factor=1, Type=RelativeToParent}">
                                            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <!--<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.RemoveItem, Source={x:Reference Name=MainView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ID}" />-->
                                            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        </Label>

                                        <Label x:Name="QuantityLabel" Text="{Binding Quantity}" TextColor="Black" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

                                        <Label Text="&#8853;" TextColor="Black" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                                            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <!--<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.PurchaseItem, Source={x:Reference Name=MainView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ID}" />-->
                                            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        </Label>

                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Rectangle Fill="LightGray" HeightRequest="2" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </SwipeView.Content>

                    </SwipeView>
                
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

**Product Class**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using SQLite;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;

namespace TakeItAwayPOS.Structures
{
    public class Product
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int Stock { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof(Category))]
        public int Category { get; set; }

        //for adding to orders
        [Ignore]
        private int quantity { get; set; }
        public int Quantity
        {
            get => quantity;
            set { quantity = value; QuantityChanged(); }
        }

        public delegate void PropertyChangedEvent(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args);
        public event PropertyChangedEvent PropertyChanged;

        private void QuantityChanged()
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
        }


    }
}
```

**CategoryGroup Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TakeItAwayPOS.Structures
{
    public class CategoryGroup : List<Product>
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public CategoryGroup(string name, List<Product> products) : base(products)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

**EditProduct Command**

```
public ICommand EditProduct
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command<string>((param) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Triggered!");
                    LoadProduct(Convert.ToInt32(param));

                });
            }
        }
```

My issue is with the `GestureRecogniser` for the `StackLayout` inside of the `DataTemplate`:

```
<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
   <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EditProduct, Source={x:Reference Name=MainView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ID}" />
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```

the CommandParameter binding wont work and the Command is only fired if I replace `"{Binding ID}"` with `"0"`:

When I hover over all of the binding items in the CollectionView, intellisense references them to the `CategoryGroup` type instead of the `Product` type that would be expected, the odd thing is that the other binding values except the Command all work even though intellisense references them to the wrong type.

My two questions are:

1. How would I go about trying to fix that command
2. Can I fix the intellisense so that it recognises when grouping is true (or is this a known issue?)

Thanks in advance!

***Solved***
Thanks @Jason!

For some reason earlier in my code, the `CommandParameter` didn't want to work as an `int` and so I had used this long winded method that converted to a string and then back to an `int` within the `Command`'s lambda method. Turns out I didn't need this and the fix was just to change the parameter type of the Command to `int` as so:

```
public ICommand EditProduct
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command<int>((param) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Triggered!");
                    LoadProduct(param);

                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: try `{Binding .}` and change the param type of your command to `object`.  Then look at it in the debugger to verify that it is a `Product`

Comment: Just done this, the Command fired and verified that it is of type `Product`

Comment: I'm going to try removing the string to int conversion and see if passing the value through as an int from start to finish will work

Comment: if `ID` is an `int` then `Command<string>` will not work.  Use `Command<int>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ID` is an `int`, so you need to use `Command<int>`, not `Command<string>`